# Brother DCP-J152W - Scanner not working with Simple Scan

Tags: scanner

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and the printer is working fine, but the scanner doesn't work in document scan. I downloaded the scanner driver from the Brother site as advised, but still not working. Some suggestions would be much appreciated.  Russell

Comment: Are you a member of the `lp` group? Also, you may want to open the `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` file for editing and add `brscan4`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but  it is now sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  had the same issue with another Brother I installed Gscan2pdf  using Synaptic Package manager    But I think it is in the snap store too  Anyway it worked.  That program can recognize my  brother. It's slow takes a bit so  let it do it's thing

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with simplescan (aka Document scanner) after upgrading to 20.04. I also had Xsane installed, which DID work.I then installed Gscan2pdf as suggested by Vladimir Petrovich in this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1294468/225694 which also worked I had to monkey with the settings to get it to understand I was using US Letter size paper but in the end Gscan2pdf was far more intuitive to use than Xsane for multi-page scans